# Conditions for market completeness

Tags: option-pricing, hedging, financial-markets

We know that a market is called *complete* if it is possible to replicate any future payoff trading in its securities. Is there an exhaustive list of requirements that when satisfied imply market completeness? Is perfect competitiveness one of those?

Answer (score 1):

A market is said to be complete if every derivative can be hedged. You can find a discussion of this, e.g. in *Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for finance II* (chapter 5). The idea is that then you can remove any source of uncertainty/risk (i.e. hedge) from the derivative in that market by taking some positions in the securities that belong to that market.

In that book he also gives an algebraic definition and discusses why that claim is mapped one to one to the uniqueness of the risk neutral measure.